# Is there any way to watch Netflix and Hulu in VR on iPhone without a computer?

Tags: iphone

The Samsung Gear VR headset, which is designed for Samsung Galaxy phones, has Netflix and Hulu apps that allow you to watch TV shows and movies in virtual reality.  My question is, is there anyway to watch Nefflix and Hulu in virtual reality on an iPhone without a computer?

I'm aware of apps that stream Netflix and Hulu from a desktop computer onto your iPhone in VR, but I want a solution that does not rely on a computer.

EDIT: [TrinusVR](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/trinusvr/id1101683353?mt=8) is an example of an app that allows you to stream Netflix from a PC to your iPhone in VR.

Comment: It may be useful if you list some of the apps you refer to so the community has a point of reference for what you're trying to achieve. For example, list some of the apps that can stream Netflix and Hulu from a computer to an iPhone.

Comment: Both are available in standalone VR on any Nougat phone or any Samsung phone compatible with Gear VR, neither is available standalone on iPhone.